# addTextChangedListener is not working on marshmallow

Tags: android

when i use (MY EditText).addTextChangedListener than it works in all devices below android 6.0 but not working on android 6.0 and upper versions. here is my code which i used

```
 email.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                  int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                      int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (!isValidEmail(s.toString())) {
                email.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#EB2525"));
            } else {
                email.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#088A08"));
            }
        }
    });
```

please help me .

thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by not working? None of the methods get called on a text change?

Comment: than what i should have to use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try this one it was helpful for me.

in oncreate method

```
  inputEmail.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher(inputEmail));
```

and here is some code :-

```
 private class MyTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

    private View view;

    private MyTextWatcher(View view) {
        this.view = view;
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
             case R.id.input_email:
                validateEmail();
                break;

        }
    }
}


 private boolean validateEmail() {
    String email = inputEmail.getText().toString().trim();

    if (email.isEmpty() || !isValidEmail(email)) {
        inputLayoutEmail.setError(getString(R.string.err_msg_email));
         return false;
    } else {
        inputLayoutEmail.setErrorEnabled(false);
    }

    return true;
}
  private static boolean isValidEmail(String email) {
    return !TextUtils.isEmpty(email) && android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
edt_email.addTextChangedListener( new GenericTextWatcher(edt_email));

private class GenericTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

    private View view;

    private GenericTextWatcher(View v) {
        this.view = v;
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why your code should help? I just don't understand it

Comment: because this code is working condition in marshmellow

Comment: Great :) It's not explanation. Why saving view to a variable inside a textWatcher changes anything? This view variable even not used.

Comment: try into other device. this code is working perfectly into my latest device.

Comment: i tried in my 4 devices  (having marshmallow)  it is not working 

but when i try this in other devices having android version below 6.0 its working perfectly